# Статистика портов

Tags: java

Получил вот такое задание: Написать программы сканер портов+проверка сканироваия с
сохранением логов **(с какого адреса, когда и по какому порту
стучались**). Со сканером портов все понятно, можно просто пробовать подключаться с каждому порту, а вот со второй частью не совсем, как собрать некую статистику с портов? Жирным выделен главный вопрос. Подскажите куда копать. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В задании от вас не требуют никакой статистики. Требуется просто записывать в лог попытки подключения.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Написать программы сканер портов+проверка сканирования с сохранением логов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822236/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вот как раз и вопрос, а как нам отлавливать эти попытки подключения

Comment: @dmitryi что значит как отлавливать? Вы во внешнем цикле, предположим, обходите адреса, а во вложенном порты, делая на каждой итерации попытку подключения. Вот и записывайте в лог результат это попытки.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev то есть нам не нужно отлавливать каждое подключение на какой-то порт, мы сами когда проверяем открыт порт или закрыт логгируем свою же проверку, так получается?

Comment: @dmitryi если я правильно понял текст задания.